# Programmatically update node image field (using URI of the image) and get URL in twig

Tags: nodes, 8, media

I am trying to update a node image field programmatically. I currently loading the node like this:

```
$node = Node::Load(1);
```

have the URI if the image that I want to set. I have tried this but no luck:

```
$node->set('field_image_head', array('#uri' => $imageUri));
```

1. How do I now update the node image with an image URI?
2. The twig will need to get the URL from the image field like so 
   `{{ file_url(node.field_image_head.entity.fileuri}}`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to create a file for the image first before you can add it to the node.

```
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\file\Entity\File;

  $node = Node::load(1);
  $uri = 'public://image.jpg';

  // check first if the file exists for the uri    
  $files = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage('file')
    ->loadByProperties(['uri' => $uri]);
  $file = reset($files);

  // if not create a file
  if (!$file) {
    $file = File::create([
      'uri' => $uri,
    ]);
    $file->save();
  }

  $node->field_image[] = [
    'target_id' => $file->id(),
    'alt' => 'Alt text',
    'title' => 'Title',
  ];

  $node->save();
```

Comment: The file is already created I think. It's the default image uploaded in content type. I have got the URI of the default image and want to set that. Would I still need to create a file for it? @4k4

Comment: I added a check if a file exists

Comment: You should `create` your file and then call the `save` method in two separate statements. As written, `$file` would be the Boolean returned by the `save` method.

Comment: how about if the image is coming from an external link. How do we save it inside Drupal?

Comment: @JohnReyTanquinco, use [system_retrieve_file](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_retrieve_file/8.6.x)  with managed set to TRUE to get $file.

Comment: @4k4 Thanks for your quick response. Im not sure how to implement that in code but I created a separate thread here. I would appreciate if you can write a simple code for it to help me. TIA

Comment: @4k4 Okay, I tried what you describe and seems to be saving the image in Drupal, unfortunately the image still not diplaying and it has no extension, it is save with filename only. Also since image filed only accepts `png, gif, jpg, jpeg`. Heres my code. `$file = system_retrieve_file($imageUri, $directory, TRUE);`