# How to add image field to paragraph programmatically?

Tags: 8, paragraphs

I am trying to programmatically add an image field value to a paragraph.

The field value of the image is as below

```
Array (
  [target_id] => 28
  [alt] => test images
  [title] =>
  [width] => 1440
  [height] => 557
)
```

This is, how I try to set the image field value:

```
$paragraph->set('field_image',  $para_array);
```

The image field is not being set. Where am I going wrong and what will be the way to implement it?

Comment: do you have a paragraph ?

Comment: Did your image exit? Did you use $paragraph = Paragraph::create([]) before use $paragraph->set and why not add image to array in Paragraph::create?

Comment: The above snippet works , the error was caused by parent for loop .

Answer (score 2):

You can treat the field like a PHP array to add (and not replace) an image:

```
use Drupal\paragraphs\Entity\Paragraph;

  $paragraph = Paragraph::load($paragraph_id);
  $paragraph->field_image[] = [
    'target_id' => $fid,
    'alt' => $alt,
    'title' => $title,
  ];
  $paragraph->save();
```

Comment: Where to add the image location URL? How will the image URL be stored on the backend? Is just the Alt enough for inserting image?

Comment: @Rick, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/227182/47547 how to lookup or create a file id for the image URL.

Comment: thanks. I am trying to select image from my SQL table and push into Drupal. this is my ticket - https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs/issues/3113055

Comment: what is target_id here? How can I find that or set that for my image? can i create a column on my table as target id, and map it?

Comment: Thanks a lot. the link you gave me helped to finish this task. :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't set the complete array. You have to just pass target_id to set the image field:

```
use Drupal\paragraphs\Entity\Paragraph;

$paragraph = Paragraph::load($paragraph_id);
$paragraph->set('field_image',  $para_array['target_id']);
$paragraph->save();
```

Comment: weight and height is computed, so those don't need to be set, but you do have to set alt/title.

Answer (score 0):

You try the code.

```
    $images = [
      'target_id' => 1,
      'alt' => '',
      'title' => '',
      'width'=>1440,
      'height'=>557
    ];
    $paragraph = Paragraph::create([
      'type' => 'paragraph_type',
      'field_images' => $images
    ]);
    $paragraph->save();
```