# Save and set an external link image programatically

Tags: 8, media, files

I have a field that will accept an image link coming from the external source. But of course, to set that image I have to save it in Drupal first. I'm wondering how do Drupal save the image from an external link. I use the following code.

```
$imageUri = 'https://api.statvoo.com/favicon/?url=google.com'; // this is a favicon

$file = File::create([
          'uri' => $imageUri,
          'status' => 1,
        ]);
$file->save();

$user_profile->field_profile_image[] = [
        'target_id' => $file->id(),
        'alt' => 'Alt text',
        'title' => 'Title',
        'width' => 200,
        'height' => 200,
      ];

$user_profile->save();
```

I notice that the following values and the external image URL were added in the image field, but the image is not displayed on the page. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think this is supported. If you want to display external links I would instead suggest to use a link field and a custom formatter. It does get more complicated if you want to mix local and remote images in the same field. Then I would suggest you use media and a custom media source plugin

Comment: This code in php does uploads image in the the desired directory. `$file_content = file_get_contents($imageUri); $directory = 'public://2018-08/'; file_prepare_directory($directory, FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY); $imageUri = file_save_data($file_content, $directory . basename($imageUri), FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);` but unfortunately, its still not able to display the image, though I can access the photo in the same directory where it upload/save the image by default(on manual upload of image in editting node page). This is what I want to achieve similarly https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/227182/70281.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think it is supported. I found an exact solution I need to be able to save and set an external image source inside Drupal according to [Programmatically update node image field (using URI of the image) and get URL in twig](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/227180/programmatically-update-node-image-field-using-uri-of-the-image-and-get-url-in/227182?noredirect=1#comment329044_227182).

I use this method [system_retrieve_file](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_retrieve_file/8.6.x).