# How can I re-populate file_usage and file_managed tables?

Tags: 8, files

I have a commerce website. I am also consuming a web service and creating corresponding products, including matching products with another table's rows. I have the below code. It ran several times and I ended up deleting file references from file_usage and file_managed tables because the table had over 300.000 rows. The code used to work before I deleted did so. Since then I tried several things, including running a bare minimum. Since then, I've been pulling mt hair. What can I do to re-populate those tables?

```
<?php
$req = Drupal::httpClient()->get('http://www.example.com/path/to/web/service');
$res = $req->getBody();
$res = json_decode($res);
foreach($res->Data as $r) { 
  $query = Drupal::database()->select('excel', 'e')->fields('e')
    ->condition('stokkodu', $r->StokKodu);
  $or = $query->orConditionGroup()
    ->condition('grupindex', 1)
    ->condition('grupindex', NULL, 'IS NULL');
  $results = $query->condition($or)->execute()->fetchAll();
    foreach($results as $result) {
      $imagename = "public://urun".$result->gorsel;
      $images = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
        ->getStorage("file")
        ->loadByProperties(["uri" => $imagename]);
      $image = reset($images);
      if (!$image) {
      $image = File::create([
        'uri' => $imagename,
      ]);
      $image->save();
      $logoname = "public://urun/logo/".$result->logo;
      $logos = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
        ->getStorage("file")
        ->loadByProperties(["uri" => $logoname]);
      $logo = reset($logos);
      if (!$logo) {
        $logo = File::create([
          'uri' => $logoname,
        ]);
        $logo->save();
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this the code that deleted the files? Do you want to repopulate the files based on the results from the webservice?

Comment: No, it was I who deleted the file references. I want to populate the tables based on the files that are already on the system.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you want. Right now you loop through the results and find/create a file based on the result. What do you want to do with that file? Do you want to save that file in another table or?

Comment: I had used https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/227182/17632 for reference and that answer told me I had to create a file object first which corresponds to the physical image on the system. Then I will use those in my products.

Comment: Ok I see, so what is the problem then? You check if the file exists and then create it if not. Isn't that correct?

Comment: Yes, but somehow it's not working anymore since I deleted those references.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102043/discussion-between-jdrupal-and-kartagis).

Comment: You got no backup? Is you re-population requiring the old ids, or do you want to handle this in a second step.

Comment: I do, but it's for 7 days, so...

Comment: And a lot happened in between? Go for the backup, it will at least reduce your data-loss.

Comment: ALWAYS TAKE BACKUP WHEN MESSING AROUND IN THE DB!

Comment: @Kartagis Can't you force it to add new files?

Comment: I don't know how to force.

Comment: Instead of checking if the file exists just create it.

Comment: I tried that too, no juice.

Comment: Something is totally wrong, best bet is to go with the 7 day old db I think.

Comment: Maybe check the error logs to see if there is something.